# after Kubuntu crash all settings lost

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, kubuntu

After I forgot to stick in the power supply of my laptop the fresh installed kubuntu 14.04 system crashed and after rebooting all settings were gone.
For example there is no shutdown or restart button any longer, WLAN module cannot be found and so on. This is very strange and frustrating. Is there an easy solution? I fear that when I install kubuntu again the same may happen again.
With unity I had no such problems the last years.

System: Acer 7740G dual boot Windows 8 kubuntu 14.04 (and dabian)

thanks in advance
greets CS

Edit: now I found something: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=254884
there is reported something about changing to the old activity id but I haven't found out how this is working but maybe one of you know how to do this?

this seems also very similar https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231109